# Do I need node.js (express) to deploy an Angular App to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku, deployment

Can I run my Angular App (build with `ng build --prod`) only with node.js / express on Heroku?

For my understanding, Angular in production does not need a node.js server but can run with only the generated static files (and some configuration). You **can** run it on a node.js server/express but it's not mandatory.

So far, in most of the tutorials I found on Google regarding Deploying an Angular App on Heroku, the instructions always setup a `server.js` file with express in the Angular app and there in the `package.json` there is often something like a `postinstall` or `heroku-postbuild` script with a `ng build --prod` command.

I guess, I'm mixing some concepts or have general misunderstanding of deployments of Angular Apps on Heroku.

Comment: You don't even need _Heroku_ to run an Angular app, and I wouldn't recommend it. Host it as a static site (since that's what it is), which can be done much more simply and cheaply, e.g. using [AWS](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=host+static+site+s3+cloudfront) or [Microsoft Azure](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=host+static+site+azure+cdn).

Answer (score 0):

No, You can also create a simple http-server and host the application. However, this won't help you to understand how your application is being server. Express-node server is a light weight and can help you define your routes.

You can also redirect any https request on this server.

```
const forceSSL = function() {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
      return res.redirect(
       ['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join('')
      );
    }
    next();
  }
}

app.use(forceSSL());
```

You can also use Docker to run angular app on Heroku.